# Showing total CPU usage by using htop

Tags: cpu, htop, cpuinfo

Online I found the following figure where you can see "CPU" as first row and it should represent the total amount of the used CPU.

[image]

Amongst the options of the htop I run on my PC there isn't the above CPU option. Where can I find it?

[image]

Comment: Hello @KGIII I tried to add CPU average; the output is Avg, not CPU.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to settings with `F2` then move right with your `right arrow key` then select how you want the CPU displayed by using `space` then `F10` to save.

Comment: Hello @Saxtheowl I did it (see the column "Available meters" in my screenshot please), but in the options there isn't CPU, I mean total amount of the used CPU.

Comment: 1 2 3 and 4 correspond to each of your processor, if you want the average of the 4 you can delete the column with delete, move to the right and add the "CPU average" to your left column

Comment: Hi @Saxtheowl, the CPU plot in the first figure should be the total amount of the used CPU, not the average.

Comment: You don't have to delete anything, you can just scroll down on the "Available meters" column after selecting the "Meters" option on the Setup drop-down of the Setup screen, to select there "CPU average". You might have to calculate the total from the average in your head, knowing the amount of cores you have, as I see no option to get a sum, only the average. You might want to look for cpu utilization tools that log all this information over time if you are after more than an eye's view of utilization.